# Java how pass class<ArrayList<T>> to method?

Tags: java, generics, gson

I get Json string and I want create universal method for convert Json string to Object.
I create object

```
public class ResponseMessage<T> {

    private T result;
    private ResultCode resultCode;
    private String details;

    public ResponseMessage(T result, ResultCode resultCode, String details) {
        this.result = result;
        this.resultCode = resultCode;
        this.details = details;
    }

    public T getResult() {
        return result;
    }

    public void setResult(T result) {
        this.result = result;
    }

    public ResultCode getResultCode() {
        return resultCode;
    }

    public void setResultCode(ResultCode resultCode) {
        this.resultCode = resultCode;
    }

    public String getDetails() {
        return details;
    }

    public void setDetails(String details) {
        this.details = details;
    }
}
```

And I want pass generic type to my class and return object. But I dont know hov do it. I create class `Converter`

```
public class Converter {
    private static Converter instance;
    private Gson gson = new Gson();

    public static Converter me() {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new Converter();
        }
        return instance;
    }

    public <T> T getModel(String jsonStr, Class<T> type) {
        T t = gson.fromJson(jsonStr, type);
        return t;
    }

    public <T> List<T> getModelList(String jsonStr, Class<T[]> clazz) {
        T[] yourClassList = new Gson().fromJson(jsonStr, clazz);
        return Arrays.asList(yourClassList);
    }
}
```

And I tried

```
String s = RESTUtil.doPost(url, formData);
ResponseMessage<ArrayList<CallDetail>> model = Converter.me().getModel(s, ResponseMessage<ArrayList<CallDetail>>.class);
```

But It is wrong. `s` - it is Json string.

```
ResponseMessage<ArrayList<CallDetail>>.class - type(I don't know how pass it)
```

Comment: Just as explained in the documentation: using a TypeToken: https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Serializing-and-Deserializing-Generic-Types

Comment: You already have a JSONObject class .. why do you want to create another method to convert JSON String to Object ? 

Check Doc here : http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html#JSONObject(java.lang.String)

Answer (score 0):

I have created a [SSCE](http://sscce.org/), which is essentially a short self contained example with the solution. Please take note of the inline comments.

Notice that we have restricted the bounds of ***MyClass*** to be extending List class.

```
package com.so34985191;

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken;

import java.lang.reflect.Type;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Solution for SO question 34985191
 */
public class GsonTest {
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    Converter converter = new Converter();

    List<Integer> sampleList1 = Arrays.asList(new Integer[] {1, 2, 3});
    List<Integer> sampleList2 = Arrays.asList(new Integer[] {5, 6, 7});

    @SuppressWarnings({"rawtypes"})
    MyClass[] test = {
        new MyClass<List<Integer>, Integer>(sampleList1),
        new MyClass<List<Integer>, Integer>(sampleList2)};

    Gson gs = new Gson();
    String jsonEncodedString = gs.toJson(test);

    // Example where the type is provided to the getModelList method
    Type listType = new TypeToken<MyClass<List<Integer>, Integer>[]>() {}.getType();
    System.out.println(converter.getModelList(jsonEncodedString, listType));

    // Trying with another example.
    Type nameType = new TypeToken<Test[]>() {}.getType();
    System.out.println(converter.getModelList(
        gs.toJson(new Test[] {new Test("Java"), new Test("Scala")}), nameType));
  }

  /**
   *
   * Utility class to convert a json encoded strings to respective types.
   */
  public static class Converter {
    /**
     * Converts the encoded json string to respective type depeding on the provided type parameter
     * @param jsonStr the string to be decoded.
     * @param type the type used for conversion
     * @return the decoded list
     */
    public <T> List<T> getModelList(String jsonStr, Type type) {
      T[] yourClassList = new Gson().fromJson(jsonStr, type);
      return Arrays.asList(yourClassList);
    }
  }

  /**
   * Container for a list of ids.
   * @param <E>
   */
  public static class MyClass<T extends List<E>, E> {
    private final T ids;

    public MyClass(T ids) {
      this.ids = ids;
    }

    public T getId() {
      return this.ids;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
      return this.ids.toString();
    }
  }

  /**
   * A sample wrapper over string.
   */
  public static class Test {
    private final String name;

    public Test(String name) {
      this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
      return this.name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
      return this.name;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Refer to the documentation here : http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html

Basically you can use the JSONObject class. It can take string as input and convert to object of JSONObject.

You can use this object to get individual elements (values) from of JSON structure.